# When high load tomcat threads sudden increase and hanged after few minutes

Tags: java, tomcat, freeze, high-load

Tomcat getting hang with high load. Tomcat threads DB connections are showing a sudden increase. ex: tomcat threads reach 1000 from 200 within a minute. normally tomcat thread shows 150 - 250 stable pattern

We have checked all application metrics and JVM metrics. But cannot identifies the root cause for this sudden instability.
below is the list that we have checked.

App - tomcat thread, tomcat CPU, tomcat memory, server memory, server CPU

DB - CPU,process,connections,memory

JVM - GC calls

TomcatThreadGraph-Nagios - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWEup.jpg

TomcatThreadGraph-DataDog - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASmQZ.jpg

Comment: Why don't you pull a thread dump, check what the threads are to see if there is anything unexpected there.

Comment: I already checked threads and memory dumps and there were no any suspicious things.that's why I mentioned above clearly "all the JVM matrices".thanks for you consideration